# Laravel Same Table Relation with UUID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have some problems with my Laravel migration.
I'm trying to add nullable parent key from same table. Like so:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->uuid('parent_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And it's always returning

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `ecommerce`.`categories` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint
> `categories_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references
> `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

But I have it in similar project, but with id, and it works like that:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
```

But how to make it with uuid to work?

Comment: You need to define the primary key on your model `public $incrementing = false; protected $keyType = 'string';`

Comment: I don't have model, it's only migration

Answer (score 2):

After created the `categories` table on 1st migration, define the foreign key on 2nd migration, as like :

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->uuid('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Above code tested with **`Laravel 8.25.0`** & **`MariaDB 10.4.14`**

Comment: `->nullable(false)` will change initial configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is foreign keys can be only applied on `primary keys` or `unique columns`. So what you can do is defining your uuid column as a primary key by doing this:

```
$table->primary('<UUID COLUMN NAME>');
```